# Can not extend generic interface without compile errors

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, android-mvp

I have the following code:

```
interface MVPView <A, B> {  
   void updateView(A a);  
   void attachPresenter(B presenter);  
}  

public class ConcreteMVPView implements MVPView<MyObject, MyPresenter> {  


}
```

This compiles fine.

But if I change the code as follows:

```
interface MVP <B> {
   void attachPresenter(B presenter);
}

interface MVPView <A> extends MVP  {  
   void updateView(A a);  
}  

public class ConcreteMVPView implements MVPView<MyObject> {  
 // how can I implement that attachPresenter?  


}
```

The code does not even compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "`extends MVP`" is using a raw type. `MVP` needs a type variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you need only implemention `MVP`, you can do it this way:

```
interface MVP<B> {
    void attachPresenter(B presenter);
}

public class MVPImpl implements MVPView<MyPresenter> {

}
```

If you want to implemention `MVPView`, you can do this:

```
interface MVP<B> {
    void attachPresenter(B presenter);
}

interface MVPView<A, B> extends MVP<B> {
    void updateView(A a);
}

public class ConcreteMVPView implements MVPView<MyObject, MyPresenter> {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Sun that if you want `MVP` and `MVPView` to use the same generic, then have `MVPView<A> implements MVP<A>` so it passes A along.

If you want MVP to have its own generic you need MVPView to have 2 generic types.

```
interface MVP<B>
interface MVPView<A,B> extends MVP<B>
class ConcreteMVPView implements MVPView<SomeClassA,SomeClassB>
```